# Multiple checkbox image replacement - only effecting first row of checkboxes

Tags: html, css, image, checkbox, replace

I am trying to replace checkboxes with images. I got the inputs hidden and the images shown using the label for the checkboxes, but when I click any of the checkboxes it only updates the first row of checkboxes. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<form action="">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="make-admin">
        <label for="make-admin"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="remove-member">
        <label for="remove-member"></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="make-admin">
        <label for="make-admin"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="remove-member">
        <label for="remove-member"></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="make-admin">
        <label for="make-admin"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="remove-member">
        <label for="remove-member"></label>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
    display: none;
}
    input[type="checkbox"] + label:before{
    content: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/26/unchecked_checkbox.png');
}
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before{
    content: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/26/checked_checkbox.png');
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/D351GN3R/8jW43/

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have no idea what's going on here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `label` elements are looking for the `id` you tied them to and you have the same `ID`s for each row. You need unique `id`s for each checkbox and to match the `for` on each `label` like so:

```
<form action="">
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="make-admin">
    <label for="make-admin"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="remove-member">
    <label for="remove-member"></label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="make-admin2">
    <label for="make-admin2"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="remove-member2">
    <label for="remove-member2"></label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="make-admin3">
    <label for="make-admin3"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="remove-member3">
    <label for="remove-member3"></label>
</div>
</form>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EWpLq/

Comment: I'd even go further and say 'You must use unique `id`s'. ;)